# Simplify Python chained comparison

Tags: python

I am writing some python code in PyCharm. It is giving me a warning when I write the following test.

```
            return factor >= 1.0 and factor <= 2.0
```

Information on the warning says it is showing because the comparison can be simplified.
Is there a better way of writing this comparison.
[image: An image showing the warning]

Comment: Doesn't PyCharm have an intention that will do the simplification for you?

Answer (score 6):

```
return 1 <= factor <= 2
```

This will eliminate that, as it's combining the two comparisons.